# Jenkins updates using Nexus repo

Tags: jenkins, nexus

I have Jenkins server that is not allowed to connect to the internet for security reasons. But Jenkins can connect to our internal Nexus repository. Is there a way to set up a nexus repository as an update server for plugins for Jenkins?  If anyone has set this up I would love to see how they did it?

Thanks,